# Showing multiple search results on leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, maps

https://www.website.ro/harta this is the map that uses leaflet.js and https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search, but i can search only single locations.

https://www.website.ro/public/ajax?q=electri

If i search for "electri" it has 3 locations, i want to show them when i hit enter, not to show "Not found".

Already searched on google, stackoverflow, didnt found similar answer/problem.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with careful use of the options that leaflet-search provides.  First, let's create an array that will hold the potential results, and a featureLayer to render any results that show up:

```js
const results = [];
var resultsLayer = L.featureGroup();
```

Now we can overwrite the `buildTip` option as a function which does pretty much what it does already by default, but pushes the results to an array as well:

```js
var controlSearch = new L.Control.Search({
  ...options,
  // hijack buildtip function, push results to array
  buildTip: (text, loc) => {
    results.push(loc); // <---- crucial line here
    // the rest of this is lifted from the source code almost exactly
    // so as to keep the same behavior when clicking on an option
    const tip = L.DomUtil.create("div");
    tip.innerHTML = text;
    L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(tip)
      .on(tip, "click", L.DomEvent.stop, controlSearch)
      .on(
        tip,
        "click",
        function (e) {
          controlSearch._input.value = text;
          controlSearch._handleAutoresize();
          controlSearch._input.focus();
          controlSearch._hideTooltip();
          controlSearch._handleSubmit();
        },
        controlSearch
      );
    return tip;
  },
  // only move to the location if there are not multiple results
  moveToLocation: results.length
    ? () => {}
    : L.Control.Search._defaultMoveToLocation
});
```

Now we add an event listener to the input of the search, and if the user presses enter, and there are multiple results, the results that were pushed into the `results` array will be added to the `resultsLayer` as markers, and added to the map:

```js
inputEl.addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {
  if (e.key === "Enter" && results.length) {
    markersLayer.remove();
    results.forEach((result) => {
      const marker = L.marker(result);
      resultsLayer.addLayer(marker);
    });
    map.fitBounds(resultsLayer.getBounds());
  }
});
```

### [Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/leaflet-search-multiple-markers-g1l8e)

Note this will likely require some cleanup work (i.e. emptying the array on new or empty searches), or readding the full data set if the search is empty, etc., but this should be enough to get you started.

### Edit - Full item info

You asked in a comment how we can get the full details of an item and put that in a popup.  Reading through leaflet-search's docs and source code, there doesn't seem to be any place that their code 'catches' the entire data object.  The `buildTip` function really only needs 2 pieces of data from an item - the text to show in the tooltip, and the location it refers to.  There's a bunch of `TODO`s regarding keeping the source data in a cache, but they're still todos.

What I would do is use the `title` and `loc` that is returned in a result to filter the original data and find its corresponding item in the original data:

```js
const getFullItem = (title, loc) => {
  return data.find((item) => item.title === title && loc.equals(item.loc));
};
```

We can also create a generic function to build the popup text for all the makers, and the results, so the popups are all consistent:

```js
const buildPopupText = (item) => {
  return `
    <h4>Title: ${item.title}</h4>
    <p>Phone: ${item.telefon}</p>
    <p>more stuff from ${item.whatever}</p>
  `;
};
```

When we hit enter and we map through the `results`, we'll use the result to get the original item:

```js
inputEl.addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {
  if (e.key === "Enter" && results.length) {
    results.forEach((result) => {
      const originalItem = getFullItem(result.text, result.loc);
      const marker = L.marker(result.loc);
      marker.bindPopup(buildPopupText(originalItem));
      resultsLayer.addLayer(marker);
    });
    map.fitBounds(resultsLayer.getBounds());
  }
});
```

So now the results popups build a popup from the `originalItem`, which has all the properties you'll need.

### [Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/leaflet-search-multiple-markers-forked-9dprx)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking.  If you want the markers in the results to have popups with information in them, you'll have to tweak the solution a bit. I altered the codesandbox to do that, check it out.  My solution (like most on SO) is not mean to just be copy/pasted, but used as a starting point to build what you need

Comment: Thanks, again, i'm trying to implement categories to markers but your code is to hard for me and i'm getting stuck. Every location has a type property which is 1 or 2, i'm trying to add every location in a specific category which shows on clicking the control from the right of the map. 1 is educational and 2 is jobs, https://codesandbox.io/s/leaflet-search-multiple-markers-forked-l2v5r

Comment: That adds a layer of complexity thats beyond this particular question.  You need to manage several related things - the retrieval of your data, the filtering of your data into subset layergroups according to their `type`, which subset layergroups are currently being searched based on whether or not they are presently on the map (according to the layers control), and once 'enter' is pressed, what markers are shown and what markers are removed.  If you're new to all this, this is a great exervise in array manipulation and managing browser events.

Comment: I was trying to get this working for you but I gotta get back to work.  [Here is a working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/leaflet-search-multiple-markers-forked-l2v5r) that properly shows filtered layers with the layers control, and properly searches only the layers that are currently shown on the map.  Its pretty buggy in that toggling the layers on and off sometimes removes more than it should from the map, but hopefully its something you can play with to get some ideas.

Comment: It work perfect on the sandbox, i've tried to change the input source for searching, i tried ajax, from what i see it doesn't work an external code for sandbox, so, i will share my link here dev.id.alin.xyz/harta - try to search something like: elec, buc, ospatar. Every time when i type enter new markers are appearing. Older one aren't hiding. Ajax is made dev.id.alin.xyz/ajax?q=buc here. If i type buc on search and enter it gives me many results on map, but ajax gives me only 2. From ajax response i have some data, but i can't show that data on popup generated on search, why? Many thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer to account for that.  There's nothing built in to leaflet-search to do that easily, so you need a little extra logic to use the results of the search to find the item in the original dataset, and use that to creat the popup.

Comment: Without seeing your code, I can't tell you what's wrong.  The code I wrote was just an example.  You will have to adapt it and work it to get things working as needed.  You're close, keep going.  If you post your code, I can help better.

Comment: You need other info or what can i do to solve this better? I'm really trying but i get undefined.

Comment: Yes unfortunately that pastebin is very difficult to read (no syntax highlighting or formatting, tons of adds).  I recommend you make a codesandbox or something similar, basically a [***minimal reproducible example***](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: https://pastebin.com/9NBu2JwS and the answer for /getFullItem?lat=43.81204483682479&long=28.580670735325793 is `{"id":1,"name":"Liceul Economic Mangalia","description":"O descriere random a locatiei 440","logo":null,"lat":"43.81204483682479","long":"28.580670735325793","type":1,"phone":"TELEFON","website":"WEBSITE","email":null,"contact_name":null,"contact_phone":null,"created_at":"2021-05-10T08:06:55.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-05-10T08:06:55.000000Z"}` Is this ok, more readeable ?

Comment: A few things.  Change `moveToLocation: results.length` to `moveToLocation: results.length > 1` on line 267.  Also, your `getFullItem` function is very wrong.  I would not make an ajax request within that function.  I would request all the unfiltered data beforehand, store it in a variable, say `allData`, and then filter `allData` as I showed in my example.  While you could do it with a per-item ajax request, this will be slow, and introduces all sort of async logic that you are not handling properly.  I cannot tell you ow much I recommend learning to use sandbox websites, pastebin is awful

Comment: I tried like your example and the markers arent showing after search, can you please give me the correct getFullItem function? I have all data stored in data var (the structure is shown on pastebin, i want to show all that data on the popup after search, website, email, etc) `const getFullItem = (lat, long)` - if can help me to build that to filter based on lat and long, not name or phone like you earlier did, i tried several version, ajax was my last

Comment: The `getFullItem` I posted should work.  However, I used `item.title`, and it looks like your data items don't have a `.title`, but rather a `.name`. 
 Try `const getFullItem = (title, loc) => {
  return data.find((item) => item.name === title && loc.equals(item.loc));
};`. At this point I believe you've got everything you need, keep trying and debugging, you'll get it.  Good luck.

Comment: I tried in another way and it works, so, in data i have: `{"loc":[{{$location->lat}}, {{$location->long}}],}` for every locations. The function is `const getFullItem = (lat, long) => {
  return data.find((item) => item.lat === lat && item.long === long);
};`. To this to work i need to add a new pair to data input, something like ``{"loc":[{{$location->lat}}, {{$location->long}}],"lat": {{$location->lat}},
     "long": {{$location->long}},}`. How can i fix my function not to add pais lat and long to my data var? In this way in works, but i dont want to reuse data that i already have

Comment: I believe you can do this on your own.  Take the time to debug.  Take a walk.  Your presentation of the question has been very poor, which is why your question was closed.  I think I've overextended myself here.  Good luck.

Comment: I have found a bug, one last thing, if a write a text the results are shown. If i hit enter only the locations found are shown, how can i mark the found location if a user select the result with the mouse? i have a lists of all results, the maps only zooms in, i dont know which marker is

Comment: Where should i look or fix this bug?

Comment: Still no succes, can you help me, please? When i manually select the entry from search results it doesnt work

Comment: Keep trying.  You can do it.